# Layer Normalization Training vs Evaluation mode in TensorFlow/Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to understand how Layer Normalization behaves in training vs evaluation mode. I thought it is similar to Batch Normalization (training updates the beta/gamma values and evaluation uses their global values). Hence I was expecting different results when `training=True/False` but the results are same. Am I missing something?

Here is the working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

tf.random.set_seed(42)

class MLPModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLPModel, self).__init__()
        
        self.flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
        self.norm = tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization()
        

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.flatten(inputs)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        x = self.dense2(x)
        x = self.norm(x)
        return x

model = MLPModel()

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=loss_fn, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=2)
```

When I use `training=True vs False`, the results are same. But when I replace the layer with BatchNorm, the results are different as expected.

```
model(x_train[:1], training=False).numpy()
```

```
model(x_train[:1], training=True).numpy()
```

Comment: LayerNormalization applies weight normalization for each sample individually, as compared to BatchNormalisation that adjusts weights for all samples based on the parameters of the respective batch. I think it should be expected that LayerNormalzation would behave the same in both training and evaluation settings.

Comment: To be more precise, the _activations_ are normalized, not weights.

Comment: @xdurch0 Can you elaborate more or share any resources to understand it better?